# Trying to automate and scrape information from LinkedIn using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web, webautomation

I want to log into a LinkedIn account then search for a company and scrape the company data,however after I automate the sign in process I keep on getting the error below

> [26224:25040:0314/123926.899:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(677)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for ponf.linkedin.com failed:
> Certificate i=0 (CN=ponf.linkedin.com,O=LinkedIn Corporation,L=Sunnyvale,ST=California,C=US) -----
> ERROR: Time is after notAfter
>
> [31640:27472:0314/123926.904:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201
> [31640:27472:0314/124052.228:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(992)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
> [29816:30512:0314/124106.578:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(525)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
> [26224:25040:0314/124107.401:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
> ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
> ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

This is the code I have written so far

```
# Importing libraries
import os
import time
import selenium 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

# print(selenium.__version__)
#To make sure the browser does not close after automation
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/"

actions = ActionChains(driver)

#Opens browser and goes to the link, and maximizes the browser
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

sign_in = ['abc223@gmail.com', 'Test123@']
key = ['FlutterWave','Data Analysts', 'Nigeria', '']

# Sleep the script for 20 seconds
time.sleep(20)

#Inputting the email address
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="session_key"]').send_keys(sign_in[0])

#Wait till the password element is visible
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="session_password"]')))

#Inputting the password 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="session_password"]').send_keys(sign_in[1])

#Clicking on the sign in button
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
                    '//*[@id="main-content"]/section[1]/div/form[1]/div[2]/button').click()

# Sleep the script till you can type in the verification code
time.sleep(30)





search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="global-nav-typeahead"]/input')
search.send_keys(key[0])
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: thats how linked-in account breaches are made :))